# SSL rules when client and server are hosted separately

Tags: java, reactjs, ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate

I'm hosting a web game on github pages. It's a react app that connects to a websocket server (via wss) running off of a linux box in my living room. I've generated a self-signed certificate for the server, and github-pages already has a Let's Encrypt certificate by default. Presumably because the cert is self signed, the client refuses to connect to the "insecure" server and I am not prompted to install the certificate or anything, because the client does have it's own separate certificate. Would just buying a real certificate solve all my problems? Should I just host the website from the same server and figure out all the stuff associated with that (I realize this is probably the best answer)? What's the public opinion on having separate ssl certificates for client and server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can add your self signed certificate to your local truststore, but it's a little work and everyone connecting to your site would have to do it.
buying a certificate would solve this problem, because it is then signed by a trusted certificate authority which allows everyone to verify your servers identity.
on the other hand, if you move your ui to the self signed server too, the web browser will prompt (respectively warn) the user about the untrusted certificate and the user is about to say wether he wants to advance to the site or not. this would "solve" the problem too.

last, but not least. it's quite common to have ui and backend separated and therefore having separated certificates too, but not in such little applications. in a big environment definitely worth it, because it's a separation of concerns.